# Как выводить сообщение в порядке очереди?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

У меня имеется 2 страницы, главная и страница вывода. На главной странице у меня форма, при отправке формы у меня запись добавляется пока что в объект, симулировал базу. Так вот, если скажем форму отправило несколько человек, нужно на странице вывода вывести сообщение первого человека, потом второго и так по очереди, аля donatealerts. Как такое правильно сделать? Можете пожалуйста показать наглядным примером? Спасибо))

Comment: Кодом покажите, что вы делаете и что не получается

Comment: Та у меня ничего там такого и нету. Просто textarea, отправка на сервер socket emit и так же отправляю на клиент и все

Comment: Тогда в чем именно проблема, если там *ничего такого нет*? Показывайте сообщения по мере получения. Еще можно метку времени добавить и по ней сортировать, а можно сразу присылать отсортированный массив клиенту, можно по одному сообщению присылать и пусть клиент занимется сортировкой. Тут тоже ничего такого сложного нет, однако вообще не поняно, что вы делаете, как это делаете, зачем и какого результата хотите достичь...

Comment: Вы не знаете, что такое donatealerts?

Comment: А причем здесь это? Знаю, не знаю, однако сути это не меняет. Полученный список можно отображать хоть по кругу, хоть по сообщению с сервера, да и вообще, как угодно, надо просто взять и сделать задуманное